# LocalBroadcastManager a number of advantages?

Tags: android

Has anyone really used this? I am so in the habit of registering/unregistering my BroadcastReceivers inside an Activity that I almost stuttered when I saw this. Does this keep all my Broadcasts to my specific Linux Process ID that my app is running on? My Actions and Extras are package specific and the ones that are not are meant to be that way to allow other applications to possibly pick up an intent. I can see one easy use, I just did a test case with an AsyncTask, ProgressDialog, and an Activity. But what is the purpose? Is this for security? I am not a linux guru and was hoping for some input.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [LocalBroadcastManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), the advantages are:

- You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so don't need to worry about leaking private data.
- It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts to your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes they can exploit.
- It is more efficient than sending a global broadcast through the system.

You can also take a look at the [LocalBroadcastManager source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java) if you'd like to determine exactly how it works.